# API trading ebay bad request get call

Tags: ebay-api

I need to call an index in ebay api tradding : getfeedback.

i see this doc : https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Concepts/MakingACall.html

so i need to use xml api production url so i get this url :

```
https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll
```

then i add my appid, version, call index, et user id like this :

```
"https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll?version=349&appid=$MyAppId&callname=GetFeedback&UserId=fnac&siteid=0"
```

And that return me a request error.
What is wrong ?